# PROBLEMAS CREANDO FUNCION QUE DEVUELVE DIFERENTES IDS - PYTHON

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en esto así que seré lo mas breve posible, debo crear una función que no requiere ningún parámetro, pero requiere dos entradas usando input(). Una de las entradas es la cantidad de caracteres y la segunda entrada es la cantidad de ID que se supone que se generarán.
He conseguido crear el id aleatorio pero cuando intento crear la cantidad de ids me salen repetidos y no de forma diferente. Lo logico es que pueda devolver diferentes ids. este es mi humilde codigo:

```
def generar_ids():
    
    tamaño = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de digitos para su ID: "))
    cantidad = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de ID's: "))
    chars= string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    generador = "".join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(tamaño))
    return "\n".join(generador for x in range(cantidad))

print(generar_ids())
    
e9rWUycifL\
e9rWUycifL\
e9rWUycifL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es que en tu línea donde defines `generador` estás creando una única combinación de caracteres, es decir, generador contiene una única cadena de caracteres y por eso en el `return` recibes N cantidad de veces el mismo "ID".

Hay varias formas de resolver el problema

### Expresión lambda

Podrías utilizar una función anónima ([O expresión lambda](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/expresiones-lambda-en-python/)) para que cada vez que se ejecute se cree una nueva cadena de caracteres. Esto en realidad es como crear otra función adentro de tu función y que se ejecute N cantidad de veces de acuerdo al valor ingresado en `cantidad`.

Ejemplo:

```
import string
import random

def generar_ids():
    
    tamaño = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de digitos para su ID: "))
    cantidad = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de ID's: "))
    chars= string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    
    # Expresión lambda
    generador = lambda: "".join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(tamaño))

    # Utilizamos la expresión lambda para obtener la cantidad correcta de ID's
    return "\n".join(generador() for x in range(cantidad))

print(generar_ids())
```

Esto imprime:

```
Ingrese cantidad de digitos para su ID:  5
Ingrese cantidad de ID's:  2
Yf1YG
zoVgh
```

### Expresión generadora

Cuando defines `generador` si incluyes también en la misma línea un `for` para `cantidad` entonces te generaría todos los "ID's"

Ejemplo:

```
import string
import random

def generar_ids():
    tamaño = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de dígitos para su ID: "))
    cantidad = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de ID's: "))
    
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    
    # Utilizamos una expresión generadora para generar todos los ID's
    # Nota como tenemos un for para el `tamaño` y otro para `cantidad`
    ids = ("".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(tamaño)) for _ in range(cantidad))
    
    return "\n".join(ids)

print(generar_ids())
```

Esto imprime:

```
Ingrese cantidad de dígitos para su ID:  5
Ingrese cantidad de ID's:  2
grUDp
Opy8E
```

### Dos ciclos `for`

Podrías hacerlo también con dos ciclos `for` anidados

Ejemplo:

```
import string
import random

def generar_ids():
    tamaño = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de dígitos para su ID: "))
    cantidad = int(input("Ingrese cantidad de ID's: "))
    
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

    # Crear una lista vacía de ID's
    ids = []
    
    for _ in range(cantidad):
        # Inicializar un nuevo ID vacío
        id_generado = ""
        for _ in range(tamaño):
            # Agregar el número correcto de caracteres
            id_generado += random.choice(chars)
        # Adjuntar el nuevo ID generado a la lista de ID's
        ids.append(id_generado)
    
    return "\n".join(ids)

print(generar_ids())
```

Esto imprime:

```
Ingrese cantidad de dígitos para su ID:  5
Ingrese cantidad de ID's:  2
WN9fq
KWVj4
```

Comment: Hermano muchas gracias. Soy nuevo en programación y estuve literalmente 5 horas con este ejercicio. Había intentado con la segunda opción pero note que encerre mal los for con las tuplas. Si te pudiera dar una abrazo lo haria. Muchas gracias. ♥

Comment: No hay de que,  saludos!